# Expose a package object's declarations to subpackages in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following packages hierarchy:

```
rootpackage
---firstpackage
---secondpackage
```

`rootpackage` contains a package object.

I know that if a file from `firstpackage` has package declaration in the form:

```
package rootpackage.firstpackage
```

the content of `rootpackage` package object will not be in the file scope, but with the following declaration it will:

```
package rootpackage
package firstpackage
```

How this strange difference is explained? And is there more transparent way to expose the package object's content to subpackages, like importing `rootpackage` package object content to `firstpackage` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package object members can be imported in the following way:

```
import rootpackage.SomeMember
```